Why do account-based wallets "sweep to omnibus"?
I was reading about omnibus wallets here and see that an exchange may want/need to sweep account-based assets to a separate omnibus account after a user deposits them to a separate address.
I understand the technical logic behind this i.e. UTXO based transactions have multiple inputs/outputs, whereas account-based transactions do not, therefore they can incur the gas fees of accumulating all assets at one address at a time where the gas fees may be cheap, which also presumably allows for better oversight/management.
However, I do not understand why users could not just deposit their account-based assets to the omnibus directly.

Do clients receive a different deposit address purely for record-keeping, so that an exchange can track who has sent them what? (I.e. what is the benefit/need of a separate deposit address, when it will incur gas fees to "sweep to omnibus" later).

Do exchanges reuse this deposit address? (unlike UTXO based transactions, where they may generate a new one each time - I assume they do reuse given this article) states an exchange may wait until the value of assets accumulates to transfer as one batch).

Why do they actually need to sweep to a new omnibus account? Is it as I speculate, for general management/oversight?


Thank you in advance.
